# QString как сравнить с LineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Как сравнить написано в `LineEdit` с каким-нибудь `QString` и вывести `true/false`

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QString strForCmp = "str for copmpare";

QString str = lineEdit->text();


if(str.contains(strForCmp)) {
    // если есть совпадение
    ...
}
```